# How to find key by value in dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to use but no output:

```
d = {'a': 1,'b': 2}
value = input()
result = None;
for key in d:
    if d.get(key) == value:
          print(key)
```

What's the problem?

And also, what's the difference between `d['1']` and `d.get('a')`?

Comment: correction: d['a']

Comment: Don't post corrections to your question in the comment section. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70812809/edit) your own question.

Comment: For starters, `input()` returns a `str`.  (Intentionally left vague to encourage further research).  And `1 == '1'` will always be `False`.

Comment: You dont find keys by values - thats not what dicts are for. The difference between `d['a']` and  `d.get('a')` is documeted in the get method and important if the key you access is NOT in the dict.

Comment: Closed with 3 different duplicates. Please read all 3.

Answer (score 0):

For you first question, the issue is that you don't convert your input to an integer:

```
value = int(input())
```

Remember, in Python `'1' != 1`.

For your second question, see this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey).